# cant get php to save filename with correct name

Tags: php, curl, fopen

For some reason, when using this code the file it outputs is just called ".jpg".

```
<?
$title = $GET['title'];
$url = $GET['url'];

$ourFileName = $title.jpg;
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);

$ch = curl_init ("http://www.address.com/url=$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$fp = fopen("images/$ourFileName",'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
fclose($fp); 

echo ("<img src=images/$ourFileName>");
?>
```

Pretty sure it has to do with declaring $ourFileName, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this line

```
$ourFileName = $title.jpg;
```

Should be

```
$ourFileName = $title . ".jpg";
```

That should do it as long as you are sure there is a value in $_GET['title'];

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure `$GET['title']` is correct? The superglobal variable for accessing the GET parameter values is `$_GET`, not `$GET`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
    $ourFileName = $title . ".jpg";

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it should be the following:

```
$ourFileName = $title.'.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely should be

```
$title = $_GET['title'];
$url = $_GET['url'];
$ourFileName = $title.'.jpg';
```

Looks like a world of security problems there though! A script that overwrites any file it has permissions to with a file of an attackers choosing!